# "Authorize" like custom Attribute in ASP.Net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I needed [Authorize] like custom Attribute in ASP.Net mvc 3/4. Something like Below.

```
[AdminOnly]
public ActionResult OpenAddListUser()
{
    //Do some actions
}
```

Here [AdminOnly] will check some user crediantials. All I needed was if AdminOnly is not valid then return some ActionResult View or Redirect to some other view like login.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  public class AdminOnly : AuthorizeAttribute
    {

        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            bool baseAuthorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
            if (!baseAuthorized) {
                     return false;
            }
            //here should be your admin checking logic
            bool isAdmin = YourLogic.IsAdmin(httpContext.User.Identity.Name);
            return isAdmin;
        }

    }
}
```